# Arch Linux - Boot only shows EFI Default Loader which doesn't work

Tags: arch-linux, boot

I installed Arch Linux on an empty SSD hard drive. I set it to use GPT and partitioned it like this:

```
sda1 Boot
sda2 Swap
sda3 Root
```

Everything went well in the installation, but the boot loader only has two entries:

```
EFI Default Loader
Reboot Into Firmware Interface
```

The former brings me back to the same menu, but this time without the EFI Default Loader selection. The latter opens the bios settings of the motherboard.

How do I make my setup boot correctly? `parted /dev/sdb print` prints out this:

```
Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32                 boot, esp
 2      538MB   17.7GB  17.2GB  linux-swap(v1)
 3      17.7GB  180GB   162GB   ext4
```

The /boot/loader/loader.conf looks like this:

```
default  arch
timeout  4
editor   0
```

And the /boot/loader/arch.conf looks like this:

```
title      Arch Linux
linux      /vmlinuz-linux
initrd     /initramfs-linux.img
options    root=/dev/sdb3 rw
```

I noticed that changing the timeout value in `loader.conf` does change the timeout of the boot menu, so I guess the config files *should* be loaded correctly, but the boot menu never shows "Arch Linux" as a choice. I checked that both `/boot/vmlinuz-linux` and `/boot/initramfs-linux.img` exist.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I had missed one thing in the setup: you have to place the `arch.conf` file in the `entries` directory under `/boot/loader`.

Answer (score 0):

You say `/boot/vmlinuz-linux` and `/boot/initramfs-linux.img` exist, but your /boot/loader/arch.conf includes `/vmlinuz-linux` and `/initramfs-linux.img`. These are the wrong paths.

Comment: The beginner's guide says that the path should be relative to $esp. I tried with `/boot` prefix, but it doesn't do anything.